# In d3, how do I apply a style to my line chart for both the line and the area under the line?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, linechart, area

I"m using d3 v4.  I want to create a line chart in which I would like to have the area beneath the line filled but I would also like to apply a style to the line itself.  I have these classes

```
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.area {                         
    fill: url(#area-gradient);                  
    stroke-width: 0px;          
}
```

but I can't figure out how to apply them to my element.  I tried

```
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("class", "line area")
    .attr("d", area);
```

but as you can see from this Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/yw46ycse/6/ , the line style doesn't appear (at least I can't see it on Mac Chrome or Firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating your single `path` like it's two separate elements.  It's just one element and your `area` call (and style) is overriding your `line` call (and style).  If you want to style them different, plot a line and an area.

```
svg.append("path")
 .datum(data)
 .attr("class", "area")
 .attr("d", area);

svg.append("path")
 .datum(data)
 .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("d", line);
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yw46ycse/7/).